# Google Sheets Dynamic Range (for finding instance number) Countif in arrayFormula

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, formulas, array-formulas

I find the instance number of a data entry by using:

```
=countif(C$2:C2,C2)
```

When filled down, this formula displays the number of times C2,C3,C4,etc. occurs above it, thus giving its "instance number".

I would like to convert this to an array formula (to avoid the need to fill down) but,

```
=arrayformula(countif(C$2:C2,C2:C))
```

does not work.  I am unsure how to convert the range argument of countif to comply with the arrayformula while keeping this range dynamic.

Example sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cApbO2HdeiaJd7yEkS1oFzxEG5wuM2XHLU7CK_OqRCA/edit#gid=0

Answer (score 1):

Adapted a solution from [here](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/-MKqwvkwpdI) which ultimately had an unknown source.

```
=ArrayFormula(if(len(A2:A),index(sort(iferror({sort(row(A2:A),A2:A,1),row(A2:A)-row()+2-vlookup(sort(A2:A),{unique(A2:A),iferror(match(unique(A2:A),sort(A2:A),0))},2,0)})),,2),))
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to `countif` with `arrayformula`:

`=ArrayFormula(COUNTIF(A1:A6,A1:A6))`

[image]

Tip: use the same range twice

Comment: Your welcome! Please tick the green flag to accept the answer.